# Is there a better term than 保護シート for the sheets drunks and criminals are wrapped in?

Tags: word-requests

In the Skeptics.SE question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36602/do-japanese-police-roll-drunks-and-criminals-into-giant-futons , one term used for sheets that police wrap drunks and criminals in is 保護シート. (There's a photo of the sheet in that question)

However, I think most of the time that term is used for the covers on smartphone screens. I tried asking some native speakers, and they said they don't know what the correct term is.

Is there a name for these sheets, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a predominant term used to describe it.  After some googling, I hvae come up with:

・シート

・ビニールシート

・保護｛ほご｝シート

・保護[用]{よう}シート

In the context of a police arrest, any one of the above would be understood.  I personally feel like I hear 「ビニールシート」 slightly more often than the others